# Should I pass package dependencies to a module function or just require them in the module file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I understand that one can pass variables to a module by exporting modules as a function with parameters for each variable you wish to pass. E.g.

```
module.exports = module.exports = function (injectedVariable) {
  app.get('/whatever', function (req, res, next) {
     // Do something with injectedVariable
  });
};
```

I understand that this is useful for passing variables like "app" around different modules. However, what is the preferred pattern for dealing with external package dependencies. I've seen code like this.

App.js

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var _ = require('underscore');
var backbone = require('backbone');
var express = require('express');
// Pretty much every other external library

var app = express();

// Code here might config some of the 3rd party modules

require('routes/main.js')(app, _, jquery, backbone, someOtherModule, someOtherModule2);
require('routes/main.js')(app, _, jquery, backbone, someOtherModule, someOtherModule2);
// Etc

// Init server etc
```

And then each route module will export a function with all the paramaters available to support the packages it needs being passed to them.

Is there any reason for doing this? Would it not be cleaner to just require('whatever') at the top of each file? Presumably, having many require()'s for the same module across different files isn't a problem as node will then just pull out its cached version stored from the first instance of require() it encountered at runtime. Which method of managing package dependencies is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason for doing this?

Using this pattern for regular modules like underscore, jquery, backbone, is blatant violation of the basic CommonJS pattern upon which node is built. Don't do it. Just require your modules directly using CommonJS syntax. For testing and dependency injection, there are CommonJS-compatible ways to do that such as [rewire](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rewire) or [injectr](https://www.npmjs.org/package/injectr).

However, it's different with the express `app` instance as that is a specific object with a certain configuration, so it's OK to pass that in. However, express 4 eliminates the most common need to use this pattern since you can mount subapplications in an outer main application.

Comment: In regards to express 4 mounting...do you mean doing app.use('/prefix', module) ? Though in this case, I would surely need to create a new app instance with express() in the module which isn't the same as passing the old app instance around. How does express 4 resolve this?

Comment: In express 4 each sub-app can do `var app = express()` independently, define it's own routes, and then be "mounted" in an outer app instance. What this means is you could have an app for your api that creates, configures, and exports its own `app` instance, and the main app could do `mainApp.use('/api', api.app)`, which is nicer encapsulation and modularity vs passing a single global `app` instance around all your modules with routes.